# creating xml adapter for XMLGregorianCalendar having XMLSchemaType(name="date")

Tags: xml, jaxb

I want to create customer JAXB Adapter for attributes having @XMLSchemaType(name="date")

How can I acheive this?

Thanks,
Harish

Answer (score 1):

You can use the generic type parameters of `XmlAdapter`. If your `XmlAdapter` is something like: `XmlAdapter<Date, MyDateType>` then the type of the actual XML element should be "xs:date", and the type of your Java object should be MyDateType.